# Cat command didn't work correctly with execvp

Tags: c, ubuntu, unix

1) I can't use some commands in this code, such as : `cat somefile.txt > somefile2.txt`
also I can't use : `cat somefile.txt | less`

2) When I use commands like : `( cd ../) (cd ./Desktop)` and then I want to exit the program, I need to execute exit commands more than one time: ie "if I use 3 cd command, I will need 3 exit commands to end the program"

```
#define MAX_ARGS 5

// Global Declarations

// Mini Functions

void remove_new_line_char(char line[])
{
    int i=0;
    while(line[i]!= '\n')
        i++;
    line[i] = '\0';
}

// Grand Functions

int read_line(char line[])
{
    fgets(line, 10000, stdin); // File Get String
    remove_new_line_char(line); // Remove New Line Charactere
    if (strlen(line) > 512)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"The Command exceeded available line length\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if (strcmp(line, "exit") == 0)
        exit(0);
    return 1;
}

int parse_line(char* args[], char line[])
{
    int i=0;
    args[i] = strtok(line, " ");
    if(args[i] == NULL)
    {
        printf("Command Line is Empty!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    while (args[i] != NULL)
    {
        int flag = 0;
        if(strcmp(args[i],"&") == 0)
            flag = 1;
        i++;
        args[i] = strtok(NULL, " "); // NULL maintains a static pointer to the previously passed string.
        if (args[i] == NULL && flag == 1)
        {
            args[i-1] = NULL; // Remove & From Argument List and Set Background Flag.
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// Main

int main()
{
    char* args[MAX_ARGS]; // Array of Strings
    char line[10000]; // String
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Shell> ");
        if(read_line(line) == 1) // No Errors
        {
            int background = parse_line(args, line);
            if(background != -1) // Command Line isn't Empty
            {
                // Fork and Execute
                pid_t child_pid = fork();
                if(child_pid == 0) // Child
                {
                    if (strcmp(args[0], "cd") == 0 && args[1]!= NULL && args[2] == NULL)  // Special Handling For CD
                    {
                        //printf("%s\n",args[2]);
                        int check = chdir(args[1]);
                        if(check == -1)
                            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid Directory\n");
                    }
                    // Handle if args[1]== NULL, Don't even execvp()
                    else   // Other Functions
                    {
                        execvp(args[0], args); // args[0] is actually the command.
                        fprintf(stderr,"an error occured in execution\n%s\n",strerror(errno));
                        //fprintf(stderr,"Invalid Instruction\n");
                    }
                }
                else // Parent
                {
                    if(background == 0)
                        waitpid(child_pid, 0);
                    wait(1000);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I suspect that I can't use any command that has characters like: `> < |`
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did your question get a "too much code" warning? Can you pare down your example to something minimal that shows what you're trying to do with `cat` and why it doesn't work in your program?

Comment: What happens with `while(line[i]!= '\n')
        i++` is `line[]` lacks a `'\n'`?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking.  Can you modify this sentence  "..i should write exit command same number of command i used before".  Also, as previously suggested, is this an MVE: [Minimum Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @chux fgets start a new blank line that i don't need so i delete it with this loop

Comment: @SherylHohman when i try to exit the program i should write exit command more than one time " if i use cd ../ command for 3 times i will use exit command three times to close the terminal"  (as each exit command exit a child process i think )

Comment: @stealththeninja i don't use cat in the code....its just a test case to test whether the program is doing well or not.

Comment: Both `cat somefile.txt > somefile2.txt` and `cat somefile.txt | less` are an *Unnecessary Use Of `cat`* (UUOc). `cat somefile.txt > somefile2.txt` is `cp somefile.txt somefile2.txt` and  `cat somefile.txt | less` is `less somefile.txt`. You are not checking whether `execvp` fails, and if it does, you need to use the `_exit` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) i can't use some commands in this code as : cat somefile.txt > somefile2.txt also i can't use : cat somefile.txt | less

In the standard shell, the `>` and `|` are operators *interpreted by the shell*, not arguments to the command.  Since in this case the shell is your program itself, if you must support those operators then you'll need to implement the appropriate redirections yourself.  Refer to `open()`, `pipe()`, and `dup2()`, and for the pipe case you'll also need judicious application of `close()`.

> 2)when i use commands like : ( cd ../) (cd ./Desktop) and then i want to exit the program, i need to execute exit command more than one time "if i use 3 cd command i will need 3 exit command to end the program"

In the special case of the `cd` command, you fork and then change directory in the child process, but the child does not terminate or exec another process.  That leaves you with two copies of your shell running.  You need to exit both before control returns to whatever process launched your program.  Possibly in that case you want to instead execute `chdir` without forking (or waiting for a child).

Comment: is there method to terminate the child after exec ??

Comment: @MoustafaUsama, generally speaking, a shell should allow the children it launches to terminate normally, but you can try to kill terminate them prematurely by sending them an appropriate signal via the `kill()` function.  Note that neither of those is appropriate for your `cd` command, however, because the directory change affects only the process in which it is performed (the *child* process in the code as you presented it).  That's why I suggested performing the `chdir()` without forking in that case.